# No handlers could be found for logger "sklearn.datasets.twenty_newsgroups"

Tags: python

I ran the example of chapter2 in the book of Python Data Science Essentials. It appeared:

```
No handlers could be found for logger "sklearn.datasets.twenty_newsgroups"
```

Here is the code of example:

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_20newsgroups
categories = ['sci.med', 'sci.space']
twenty_sci_news = fetch_20newsgroups(categories=categories)
```

Answer (score 3):

This happens because `twenty_newsgroups` dataset is not downloaded on your system.

Run your example code like this.

```
import logging
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_20newsgroups
logging.basicConfig() # to show logging message of what is happening behind the scene.

categories = ['sci.med', 'sci.space']
twenty_sci_news = fetch_20newsgroups(categories=categories)
```

It will show the message what is happening behind the scene. Try to debug accordingly.

Hope it helps!